# KerasLayer model increased size after fine-tuning

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I am working with Universal Sentence Encoder (v4) as TF KerasLayer. I load the model, fine-tune and save it back to the file. The original size of the model is 1GB, but if I fine-tune it (without adding any Dense Layer) the size increased to 3GB. If I just load and save the model (without fine-tuning) the size remains the same.

Why there is such an increase in memory footprint? I was thinking that the original model is using some form of quantization but then it is strange to me that even the training is not performed with a different floating points:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_addons as tfa
import tensorflow_hub as hub
```

then:

```
x = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=[], dtype=tf.string)
tmp_output = hub.KerasLayer('https://tfhub.dev/google/universal-sentence-encoder/4', trainable=True)(x)
model = tf.keras.models.Model(x, tmp_output)
model.save("/media/petrlorenc/Data/universal-sentence-encoder_fine/")
```

vs

```
x = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=[], dtype=tf.string)
tmp_output = hub.KerasLayer('https://tfhub.dev/google/universal-sentence-encoder/4', trainable=True)(x)
model = tf.keras.models.Model(x, tmp_output)
model.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(0.001),
              loss=tfa.losses.TripletSemiHardLoss())
model.fit([f"sentence {x}" for x in range(size)], y=[random.randint(0, 5) for _ in range(size)], epochs=1, batch_size=128)
model.save("/media/petrlorenc/Data/universal-sentence-encoder_fine/")
```

Comment: Have you tried this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58798769/10475762

Comment: their solution solve the problem with HDD memory (now both has the same size) but introduce different error with RAM memory - if I load, fine-tune and save the model and then do inference I get an warning ``function recreate_function.<locals>.restored_function_body at 0x7fce100371f0> triggered tf.function retracing.`` and increased RAM memory consumption

Comment: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/34025 apparently that's a problem with RNN layers. Some people have solved it by upgrading their TF version.

Comment: Did you tried as suggested above?